# After disabling SMB v1 on server and workstations, files from mapped drive get "Invalid Signature" error when opened

Tags: domain, file-sharing, windows-10, server-message-block, windows-server-2016

For a newly installed Domain Controller I uninstalled SMB v1 and created a GPO that would disable SMB v1 on the domain-joined PC's in an attempt to reduce the effects of a ransomware infection.

I've found that these PC's receive an error message - "Invalid Signature" - when a file is opened from one of the mapped network shares (mapped via NET USE), but this error is only received the first attempt.

If you try again, the file opens fine.

How can I fix this without re-enabling SMB v1?